# 1D Brownian motion: stopping time and stopping state not independent

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, brownian-motion

I am trying to learn Brownian motion on my own and attempting some exercises.

Let ${X_t}$ be a standard 1D Brownian motion and define

$$T=\inf \{t:X_t=1 \ or \ -3 \}$$

The question is: show that $T$ and $X_T$ are not independent.

Intuitively, this makes sense because $1$ is closer to the origin than $-3$, so if $T$ is very small, the Brownian motion probably has not displaced much so probably $X_T =1$. As $T$ gets larger, the probability starts shifting towards $X_T=-3$.

However, I can't seem to prove the absence of independence mathematically. Although this is one possible approach (albeit maybe unnecessarily overkill), is it possible to find $P(X_T = 1 | T=t)$ and directly show that it depends on $t$? As a bonus, $P(X_T = 1 | T=t)$ would be interesting to look at.

**Source:** Introduction to Stochastic Processes, by Lawler, Problem 8.13(b).

Comment: It suffices to show that $E(TX_T)\ne0$ since $E(T)$ is finite and $E(X_T)=0$. Now, considering the first hitting time $S$ of $\pm1$ and the first hitting time $R$ of $\pm2$ and using the Markov property, one sees that $E(TX_T)=E(SX_S)+E(TX_T\mid X_0=-1)P(X_S=-1)$. Now, using symmetry four times (I believe), one gets $E(SX_S)=0$, $P(X_S=-1)=\frac12$, $E(TX_T\mid X_0=-1)=E(R(-1+X_R))=-E(R)$, hence, finally, $E(TX_T)=-\frac12E(R)\ne0$.

Comment: @Did Thanks for your answer. But instead of $E(SX_S)$ in the first long equation, I got $E(SX_T)$. Is that a typo?

Comment: @Did Nvm I realized that both are equal to 0

Comment: No typo, thanks.